# Request Timeout

Tags: magento1.9.3.1, timeout

Can anybody help me to resolve the following issue.

Request Timeout

This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

this error appears,
1. when i do re-indexing 
2. after saving some configuration (system/configuration)

I have increased the execution time,check here 
http://watoz.alphalogichq.com/phpinfo.php

Thank you

Comment: 1) max_execution_time should be set to 30 seconds only. Because no code should take longer than 30 seconds to execute. If its taking more then you should check your code or server configuration.
2) Try to run indexing from terminal.
3) Also check if there are some errors in server error log, magento error logs. There has to be.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with magento 2 site, especially while importing bulk product CSV, Appreciate if you could share the solution. Error message
Request Timeout
This request takes too long to process, it is timed out by the server. If it should not be timed out, please contact administrator of this web site to increase 'Connection Timeout'.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=noabort:1]
RewriteRule .* - [E=noconntimeout:1]
```